# flask app object inside blueprint

Tags: python, global-variables, global, flask

I know the way to access the flask app obj is using `current_app`, however, everytime I run that code I get this error: **NameError: global name 'current_app' is not defined**

What am I doing wrong here?

My folder structure is this:

```
/project
   gateway.py
   settings.py
   /app
      views.py
      models.py
```

I can't access the app object neither from views.py or models.py :S Always get the same error.

The views.py file declares a blueprint wich is registered in the gateway.py file.

I'm using `current_app` inside a view function inside the views.py file.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add `from flask import current_app` inside those files?

Comment: Do you have the __init__.py defined ? If so where are you "creating" the current_app object? Are you importing what @AudriusKažukauskas said in your views.py?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have

```
from flask import Flask, current_app
```

in your code and make sure you call it correctly, because in some context it doesn't get called.